# Converting images to ext4 format and back creates bad flash file

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms

I am trying to create a Rockchip custom ROM by getting an existing custom ROM, unpackaging it, making small modifications, then packaging it back up again.

There is a problem with me converting the `system.img` file from sparse android format to extformat and back again. There are no errors, but when I flash the resulting pacakge, the device fails to start.

Here's an experiment I've done:

```
simg2img system.img system-raw.img
img2simg system-raw.img converted-back.img
```

If I type `file system.img`:

> system.img: Android sparse image, version: 1.0, Total of 1048576 4096-byte output blocks in 697 input chunks.

If I type `file converted-back.img`:

> converted-back.img: Android sparse image, version: 1.0, Total of 1048576 4096-byte output blocks in 9674 input chunks.

Should I be adding some parameter to `img2simg`, or should I be using a different tool to create the sparse image file?

To confirm it is actually the sparse image conversion that's the problem and not something else, I have successfully done the following:

- Used `rkImageMaker` to unpack the original firmware image (which produces a bootloader and a new package file with the header 'RKAF')
- Used `afptool` to unpack this package file to a number of different files, including `system.img`
- MODIFIED NOTHING
- Used `afptool` to repackage these image files into an RKAF file
- Used `rkImageMaker` to package the bootloader and the RKAF file into a RKFW file.

This newly create RKFW image file can be flashed to the device, no problem. It's only when I add `simg2img` and `img2simg` into the mix that things go wrong.

More details:

- I am getting `aftptool` and `rkImageMaker` from here: https://github.com/rockchip-android/RKTools
- I got `simg2img` and `img2simg` by typing `sudo apt-get install android-sdk-libsparse-utils`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the tool `img2simg` to convert the raw image back to a sparse image. (Even though it seems logical to do so).

The tool that you use to create the sparse system img file is `make_ext4fs`.

I got this tool by *building the entire android source tree* for the version and target architecture. (Which took days to figure out)

Here's how I finally invoked the make_ext4fs application. (The build was in the subfolder ~/aosp_build).

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/system
sudo mount -O pipe system-raw.img /mnt/system
sudo ~/aosp_build/out/host-linux-x86/bin/make_ext4fs -s -l 4096M -a system -S ~/aosp_build/out/target/product/generic_arm64/root/file_contexts.bin ./converted-back.img /mnt/system
```

Here is my sketchy understanding of the parameters:

```
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|  Parameter                  |  Meaning                                 |
+=============================+==========================================+
| -s                          | Output to be in sparse image format      |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| -l 4096M                    | Target size of the output image          |
|                             | (I wanted it to be the same size as      |
|                             | the source image, to avoid packaging     |
|                             | complications)                           |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| -a system                   | Something about setting an android mount |
|                             | point.                                   |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| -S <path>/file_contexts.bin | Something to do with permissions         |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| ./converted-back.img        | The output image name                    |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| /mnt/system                 | The source folder (generated by mounting |
|                             | the raw image)                           |
+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Other things I discovered:

- There is a Ubuntu package [android-sdk-ext4-utils](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/android-sdk-ext4-utils) which includes `make_ext4fs`. But this doesn't work! It was built without Android support. (See [this discussion](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=741510) )
- There are a number of forks of the `make_ext4fs` packages on github. (eg [here](https://github.com/iglunix/make_ext4fs.git)). These are pinned to a specific android version. I don't know if the tool differs much from version to version. I still needed the `file_contexts.bin` file, so these were not useful to me.
- I opened up the device and saw the motherboard had a serial DEBUG output. After buying the necessary USB adapter I could read the bootloader debug output through PuTTY. This was extremely useful.